# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS not working

Tags: 14.04, grub2, gnu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and i am unable to boot my laptop from yesterday.

it directed to GNU grub version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.3 window and i have to select one from followings

1. Ubuntu
2. Advanced option for ubuntu
3. memort test (memtest86+)
4. memort test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

when i select option 1 above, it goes to purple color screen displaying UBUNTU in the middle. nothing happen thereafter.

When I select option 2 above, i got following list

Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-50-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-50-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-49-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-49-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-43-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-43-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-41-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-41-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-37-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-37-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-33-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-33-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-31-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-31-generic (recovery mode)

if i select any of above it will display so many text and end up with following error.

Kernel Panic - Not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00

Then I tried to make bootable USB with ubuntu 15.10 and when i try to install it it ask me to backup Dell software and there are 3 buttons on it Quit, back and Next. but only quit button is accessible and quit the installation.

How can you help on this.

I am using Dell i3 4005 machine.